# ajax function on change dropdown Value

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Hie Everyone!
In PHP page1 my code is here..

```
    <html>
    .
    ...
    <select id="customer">...</select>
    ..
    ....
    <div id="show"></div>
    //and Java script function (ajax call)
   <script>
   $('#customer').change(function(){
        var Id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page2.php",
        data: "ID="+id,
        success: function( data ) {
            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
    </html>
```

In php page2 as code..

```
<?php
$ID=$_GET['ID'];
...
//db connection code
..
$sql="select * from Table1 where id='$ID'";
//result code..
//while loop..
//echo something..
// all working without error..
?>
```

So, when I was trying to do this.It does not showing the success data or may be Ajax function not work.I had check with alert(data);
but does not Alert anything.
please help.

Comment: what output of url `page2.php?ID=[some id]`?

Comment: data: "ID="+id, var Id = $(this).val(); - try with uppercase, fix this: data: "ID="+Id - uppercase 'I'.

Comment: you will give  echo infront of the $ID variable <?php
echo $ID=$_GET['ID'];
...
//db connection code
..
$sql="select * from Table1 where id='$ID'";
//result code..
//while loop..
//echo something..
// all working without error..
?>

Comment: Sorry guys..But id and Id problem is just here when I paste my code. It all right in my original page.

Comment: Its still not working

Answer (score 2):

You will give echo infront of the $get_id variable. But you will make sure only one echo in the page2.php page.

```
<?php
echo $get_id=$_GET['pass_id'];
...
//db connection code
..
$sql="select * from Table1 where id='$get_id'";
//result code..
//while loop..
//echo something..
// all working without error..
?>
```

Then in page1.php check your ajax response. using alert function.

```
 <script>
   $('#customer').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "page2.php",
        data: "pass_id="+id,
        success: function( data ) {
              alert(data);

            document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = data;
        }
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Yes I did this alert..But nothing alert.

Comment: are you using firebug tool? what error you are getting in firebug console?

Comment: and make sure you will get dropdown value in the jquery function before sending the data to ajax page..

Comment: It shows me this error.."NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost/.. my page path...

Comment: if you dont mind can you send me the files? i will check and let you know.

Comment: Pls check yur mail:-).