# Load sql data after making a choose out a select box?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

I have a question.
I want to achieve something, however, I have never done this so unfortunately I do not know how to handle this.

In my screen I fill a dropdown box with names from a sql db.
Now I would like, as soon as a name is chosen from that dropdown that the other data be loaded such as, for example, min and max values.
I would like to use these values ​​to, for example, be able to give limits to input fields.
So as soon as an entry field falls outside of the loaded values, the entry field then turns red.
However, I would like to use this without the submit button of the form being pressed.

Is this possible ? if so can someone help me with this?

The code i use to fill my selectbox is this.:

```
<td>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="prod" id="employee" onclick="updateBottomValue(this.value);" onchange="mys1()" style="width: 245px;">
            <option value="" disabled selected="selected[]" multiple="multiple">Selecteer Product</option>
            <?php
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM specsv1 where RActive = 'y' order by RNaam";
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($Id,$RNaam));
            Database::disconnect();
            while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row['Id'] . "'>" . $row['RNaam'] . "</option>";
            } 
            ?>
        </select>

        <?php if (!empty($ProductError)): ?>
            <span class="help-inline"><?php echo $ProductError;?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <span id="selectedValue"></span>
    <input STYLE="width: 6em" name="rrss" type="text"  id='rrss'>
</td>
```

The code i have to get the selected name is this.:

```
<script>
    function updateBottomValue(selectedvalue) {
        document.getElementById("selectedValue").innerHTML=selectedvalue;
        document.getElementById('rrss').value = selectedvalue;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use Jquery::ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yap it is possible.

And maybe this example ajax for what you want, feel free to modify to fit your requirements.

```js
function viewMinMax(value){

    if (value == 'a'){
        tempurl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/dv40y";
    }else if (value == 'b'){
        tempurl = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/egjmq";
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: tempurl,
        type: "get", 
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: {}, //this is data you send to your server
        success: function(res)
        {   
            $('#info').show();
            document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = 'Your min value: ' + res.min + ', Your max value: ' + res.max;

            $('#min').val(res.min);
            $('#max').val(res.max);
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
    <select name="product_select" id="product_select" onchange="viewMinMax(this.value)">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
        <option value="a">Product A</option>
        <option value="b">Product B</option>
    </select>

    <p id="info" style="display:none;"></p>

    <h3>Load the min & Max</h3>
    <label for="min">Min</label>
    <input type="text" name="min" id="min" value="">
    <br>

    <label for="max">Max</label>
    <input type="text" name="max" id="max" value="">
</form>
```

ignore the `tempurl` it can be change with your action to select data based on value to your DB.

Comment: this looks promise, but you fill the data in forehand and not from a sql server, so if i fill my select box with data from sql how can i then make the function if i can't fill in the value?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? Absolutely. There are a few ways of going about it. One easy way is to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to fire off what's called an [AJAX call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) as soon as the [dropdown value changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29095234/ajax-function-on-change-dropdown-value). The AJAX call your PHP script and get back some HTML that it will [place](http://api.jquery.com/html/) wherever you want it on the screen.

It's a big subject, so difficult to give you exact answers, but google `jquery ajax dropdown onchange` and you should be able to get enough information to get you going. One of them is the following (there are many):
 [jQuery Load form elements through ajax, from onchange event of drop down box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344747/jquery-load-form-elements-through-ajax-from-onchange-event-of-drop-down-box)